# How does a singleton property with a lock ensure thread safety?

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, locking, singleton

I rarely use singletons, in this case it's appropriate.  While trying to investigate the best implementation thereof I came across this bit of code which has left me believing I improperly understand how brackets encapsulate a "scope."

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm confused what happens when I attempt to access "Instance."  Say I'm working on a logging singleton (my useful application for a singleton) and it has a method "WriteLine(string line)"

When I call:

```
Singleton.Instance.WriteLine("Hello!");
```

It maintains the lock during the execution of the entire method of "WriteLine?"

What if I assign the instance to an external variable like:

```
Singleton Console = Singleton.Instance;
```

Now there's a constant reference to the singleton outside of the singleton.  Is `Console.WriteLine("Hello!")` also completely thread safe like `Singleton.Instance.WriteLine("Hello!")`?

Anyway, I'm just confused how this makes the singleton thread safe and whether or not it's only thread safe when the property is explicitly accessed.  I thought `Singlton.Instance.WriteLine("...")` would pull out the Instance first, thereby leaving the scope of the lock, and then execute `WriteLine` on the returned instance, therefore performing the write after the lock has been released.

Any help on clearing up my misunderstanding of how this functions would be appreciated.

Comment: Not the question of course, but any reason not to use Lazy<> instead of a custom singleton here?

Comment: You seem to regard a lock as something magical that somehow makes all code safe that touches it. Notice, that the lock is released when the getter returns. All effects that the lock has cease at that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does `Singleton.Instance.WriteLine("Hello!");` maintain the lock during the execution of the entire method of `WriteLine`?

No, the lock guards only the creation of your singleton. `WriteLine` executes unlocked (unless, of course, it obtains its own lock internally).

> Is `Console.WriteLine("Hello!")` also completely thread safe like `Singleton.Instance.WriteLine("Hello!")`?

It is equally as safe or unsafe as `Singleton.Instance`, because the lock is not maintained outside of `Instance`'s getter.

> Anyway, I'm just confused how this makes the singleton thread safe

Lock makes the process of obtaining the instance of your singleton thread-safe. Making the methods of your singleton thread-safe is a process that does not depend on whether your object is a singleton or not. There is no simple turn-key one-fits-all solution for making a thread-unsafe object behave in a thread-safe way. You address it one method at a time.

Comment: Thanks, apparently I wasn't really thinking about the context of "thread safe" when reading these articles.  It was leading me to believe that the entire singleton could be accessed with thread safety which, apparently rightly, didn't make any sense to me.

Comment: The idea of multiple threads trying to create a singleton simultaneously seemed too obscure to even worry about - like one of those "one a billion chance that it happens" things.  When I think "thread safe" - I'm thinking you're engaged in huge numbers of access to the object so the thought that "thread safe" meant "thread safe creation of the singleton which happens once and is doubtful that it would ever happen with multiple threads trying to do it" just didn't occur to me...

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse Some versions of Visual Studio have a bug where function-local static singletons aren't initialized in a thread safe way and it bit lots and lots of people very, very badly. Remember, the construction of the singleton can take a non-negligible amount of time. Consider, for example, a singleton whose construction involves making a database connection. It absolutely is not at all doubtful that it would happen. If you don't prevent it from happening, it can happen.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz lol, I fixed this problem a long time ago.  I have a fully threadsafe (Console : LineFeeder) class now.  When I first wrote my "Console" class for C# years I was just learning C# and when I came back to rewrite it last May, I was confused because I had, in the original Console class, misinterpreted this accessor as making the whole class thread safe and so when I was rewriting it, I looked at it I thought: "there's no way this is actually thread safe..."

Answer (score 5):

No, the lock ends upon the `return`, anything you do with the `Instance` is "outside" the lock.

The advantage of the `lock` in that point is only one:

- It guarantees that there can be only one instance of `Singleton` that is created.

Note that in general, it is better to use the `Lazy<>` class. To obtain the same result you would have to use it like:

```
public static Lazy<Singleton> Instance = new Lazy<Singleton>();
```

(`Lazy<T>` can work in three [modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode.aspx), the default one, `ExecutionAndPublication`, is equivalent to that code)

Comment: How is that something that can be, therefore, called "thread safe?"  It just means it's thread safe as in the extremely unlikely case that multiple threads try to create the singleton at once it will only be one singleton?

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse It can't. You are right. The correct definition is that the creation of the `Singleton` is thread safe, and up to one singleton is created. Note that sometimes the creation of multiple singleton could still be thread safe, if only one is then selected as the "true" singleton. It is the process of "selection" that must be thread safe. See for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode.aspx the various modes of functioning of `Lazy<T>`

Comment: I'll look into the "Lazy<T>" implementation.  In general I try to stick with more deprecated methods due to the fact that I like my code to be compatible with Mono.  Though I think Mono now covers .NET 4.0

Answer (score 4):

> Any help on clearing up my misunderstanding of how this functions would be appreciated.

In [Head First Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do), there's a great example of a thread-safe singleton that uses "code magnets" where you can consider all the possible ways two threads can execute the same code. It's done with three columns, one for each of the two threads, and a third column for the value of the supposed singleton that is returned. It's an exercise where you position the code fragments vertically to show the sequence of operations between the two threads. I'll try to reproduce it here with limited formatting in SO and with your code example.

The code fragments (without the lock) would be:

> ```
> get{
> ```
>
> ```
>     if (instance == null){
> ```
>
> ```
>         instance = 
>             new Singleton(); }
> ```
>
> ```
>     return instance; }
> ```

You can find one possible execution that results in two instances of the class being returned, because of the way the threads execute:

> ```
> Thread One                   Thread Two                       Value instance
> ```
>
> ```
> get{                                                          null
> ```
>
> ```
>                              get{                             null
> ```
>
> ```
>     if (instance == null){                                    null
> ```
>
> ```
>                                  if (instance == null){       null
> ```
>
> ```
>         instance = 
>             new Singleton(); }                                Object_1
> ```
>
> ```
>     return instance; }                                        Object_1
> ```
>
> ```
>                                      instance = 
>                                            new Singleton(); } Object_2
> ```
>
> ```
>                                  return instance; }           Object_2
> ```

With the `lock` just after `get {`, `Thread Two` would not be able to continue (as above), until `Thread One` has executed the `return instance;` and releases the lock:

> ```
> Thread One                   Thread Two                       Value instance
> ```
>
> ```
> get{ [takes lock]                                             null
> ```
>
> ```
>                              get{ [blocks on lock]            null
> ```
>
> ```
>     if (instance == null){                                    null
> ```
>
> ```
>         instance = 
>             new Singleton(); }                                Object_1
> ```
>
> ```
>     return instance; } [releases lock]                        Object_1
> ```
>
> ```
>                                  [continues] 
>                                  if (instance == null) {      Object_1
> ```
>
> ```
>                                  return instance; }           Object_1
> ```

Comment: This is a very effective way to look at at it.  My confusion came from the fact that I was, stupidly, under the impression that such a method made the entire singleton and all its methods thread-safe which is obviously why I was confused because the accessor doesn't actually seem to do that (because it doesn't do that).  I hadn't really thought about the case where two threads would attempt to create the singleton at the same time as I usually think about thread safety in the sense of repeated ad nauseum calls to methods from multiple threads rather than the thread safety for the constructor.